# Enable posting in browser (post.php?name=MyName&body=MyText?)

Tags: php, database, post

I've created a text posting website. Except the posting on the post.php page I want to enable users to post text when they type www.mywebsite.com/post.php?name=MyName&body=MyText? How can I make this?

The post code looks like this:

```
  <?php


  //insert category to database
  if(isset($_POST['qty'])) {
    // Fetch and clean the <select> value.
    // The (int) makes sure the value is really a integer.
    $qty = (int)$_POST['qty'];


    // Create the INSERT query.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`quantity`)
            VALUES ({$qty})";

    // Connect to a database and execute the query.
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('MyServer', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('database_name', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Check the results and print the appropriate message.
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}



     if ($_POST['post'])
{
    //get data
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    //check for existance
    if ($title&&$body)
    {
        mysql_connect("MyServer","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        //insert data
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('','$title','$body','$date')") or die(mysql_error());

        die("Your text has been posted!");

    }
    else
        echo "Please fill out your name and text";
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?
Otherwise take a look at superglobal GET variables, and don't forget to secure your code against SQL injections ...

Comment: Poor example and source code. URL referenced does not contain parameters expected for the code to successfully work. Please provide accurate code and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use $_GET not POST for the data from the query string.

```
//get data
$title = $_GET['title']; // or name if it's name
$body = $_GET['body'];
```

Comment: So I should just replace the $_POST with $_GET?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I try to post it just says: Please fill out your name and text...

Comment: is the if statement still looking for a post? maybe change that to a get.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $_REQUEST - it has all the data you have posted to the script (from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE global arrays)

Comment: I think this would be the best way to refactor your code. Change $_POST to $_REQUEST and you are done!

Comment: Well, when I replaced the $_POST with $_REQUEST it works fine when I'm posting in the normal way. But when I try to type in www.mywebsite.com/post.php?name=MyName&body=MyText? it doesn't post any text...

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion is, avoid direct queries based on query strings at all possible costs! This is a huge security concern.

Also, the code you supplied would is open to numerous security holes and concerns.

Anytime you call a variable via $_COOKIE, $_POST or $_GET and it is used in a query, use MySQLI/PDO Prepared statements when possible, or at least mysql_real_escape_string. This will attempt to sanitize the data going into your database.

Also, You are GETTING parameters from the the url/query string, change POST to GET.

Additionally, your line which says:

```
if($_GET['post'])
```

Will always fail, you do not have a parameter in your url called post. For that to work, it would need to look like:

```
post.php?post&name=MyName&body=MyText?)
```

See below:

```
<?php

//insert category to database
// makes sure qty is numeric # added by sixeightzero
if(isset($_GET['qty']) && is_numeric($_GET['qty'])) {
// Fetch and clean the <select> value.
// The (int) makes sure the value is really a integer.
$qty = (int)$_GET['qty'];


// Create the INSERT query.
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`quantity`)
        VALUES ({$qty})";

// Connect to a database and execute the query.
$dbLink = mysql_connect('MyServer', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db('database_name', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

$result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string($sql));     
// sanitizes input # added by sixeightzero

// Check the results and print the appropriate message.
if($result) {
    echo "Record successfully inserted!";
}
else {
    echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
}
}



if (!isset($_GET['name']) && !isset($_GET['body'])){

//get data
$title = $_GET['name'];
$body = $_GET['body'];

//check for existance
if ($title && $body)
{
    mysql_connect("MyServer","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    //insert data
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($body)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')") or die(mysql_error());
    // sanitizes input # added by sixeightzero

    die("Your text has been posted!");

}
else
    echo "Please fill out your name and text";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks good. But now when I try to post the site just refresh and no texts are added?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete source code!!
Try using this

```
  <?php


  //insert category to database
  if(isset($_POST['qty'])) {
    // Fetch and clean the <select> value.
    // The (int) makes sure the value is really a integer.
    $qty = (int)$_POST['qty'];


    // Create the INSERT query.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`quantity`)
            VALUES ({$qty})";

    // Connect to a database and execute the query.
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('MyServer', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('database_name', $dbLink) or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Check the results and print the appropriate message.
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}



     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") //check whether its a GET method
{
    //get data, since you know that a valid "GET" request was sent
    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];


    if (isset($title) && isset($body)) //check for existance
    {
        mysql_connect("MyServer","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        //insert data
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('','$title','$body','$date')") or die(mysql_error());

        die("Your text has been posted!");

    }
    else
        echo "Please fill out your name and text";
}
?>
```

Comment: you can also put a if statement to check if the request method is GET, so you can avoid executing first few lines.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is basically the result of `array_merge($_GET,$_POST,$_COOKIE)`, so you can use it to get a value which may be a GET or POST variable.